# Error in ParseDataFeedJSON(GA.Data) : code : 403 Reason : User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile

Tags: google-analytics

I´m getting this error just after trying to extract the data and store it in a data-frame

ga.data <- GetReportData(ga.query, oauth_token, split_daywise = T)

I'm Getting this error:

> ga.data <- GetReportData(ga.query, oauth_token, split_daywise = T)
> Setting Max Results to 10000 for efficient Query Utilization
> Access Token is valid
> [ Run 0 of 353 ] Getting data for 2016-12-31
> Error in ParseDataFeedJSON(GA.Data) :
> code : 403 Reason : User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As a first guess I would say that possibly the user does not have sufficient permissions for this profile. If you expect otherwise, you should give some more details. That looks like R code, so I guess the first question would be, did you supply a valid oauth_token?

Comment: outh_token is validated